# How to manually join two different table with different attribute name in Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, join

I am currently making a website that runs on Ruby on Rails. I am facing some issues while I was trying to join two tables, ***Rates*** and ***Locations***, that I have with two different attributes name.

**Rates:** `id rater_id rateable_id` (and a few more attributes in this table)

**Locations:** `id title body user_id` (and a few more attributes in this table)

Here is the query that I am trying to do in SQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rates, locations
WHERE rates.rater_id = locations.user_id AND rates.rateable_id = locations.id
```

I have read the official active record documents that provided by rubyonrails.org. I have tried doing these, but it does not work. Here is the code that I am trying to implant in `app\controllers\users_controller.rb`

```
@join_rating = Rate.joins(:locations).where("rates.rateable_id = locations.id AND rates.rater_id = locations.id")
@all_rating = @all_rating.where(rater_id: @user)
@count_all_rating = @all_rating.count
```

`@join_rating`, is trying to join the attributes with different names.

`@all_rating`, is trying to filter which location to show using the user ID

`@join_rating`, is trying to calculate the total numbers of locations that are rated by the user

Assume that everything is setup correctly and the only error is in the query that I am trying to do, how should I rewrite the statement so that I am able to show the locations that the user has rated using `@all_rating`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

When in ActiveRecord you're starting a statement with the `Rate` class, it means the result is going to be a collection of `Rate` objects. So if you're trying to show **locations**, you should start with a `Location` class.

> @locations_user_rated = Location.joins('INNER JOIN rates ON
>   rates.rateable_id = locations.id').where('rates.rater_id' => @user)

And if your ActiveRecord associations are well defined, you could simply do:

> @locations_user_rated = Location.joins(:rates).where('rates.rater_id' => @user)

"Well defined" simply means you'll need to do something like the following. Note that I am not sure I understand your model relationships correctly. I assume below that every location has multiple rates, and that the reason your `Rate` model has the field called `rateable_id` instead of a `location_id` is because you want `:rateable` to be [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). This means you probably also have a `rateable_type` field in `rates` table.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates, as: :rateable
end

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rateable, polymorphic: true
end
```

If this polymorphism is not the case, things should actually be simpler, and I highly recommend that you follow Rails's conventions and simply name the relationship field `location_id` on your `Rate` model instead of `rateable_id`. Then you can do:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates
end

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

If still you are not convinced about the field name, you can customize things and do:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates, foreign_key: :rateable_id
end

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, foreign_key: :rateable_id
end
```

You can find more about how to customize associations [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. You made a typo in the where clause. But I am able to catch it.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know which typo so I can update the answer.

Comment: `('rates.rater_id' => @user.id).where("rates.rateable_id = locations.id AND rates.rater_id = locations.user_id")` <<< user_id

Comment: Updated: `@locations_user_rated = Location.joins('INNER JOIN rates').where('rates.rater_id' => @user).where("rates.rateable_id = locations.id")` <<< this is the correct answer. Please use this

Comment: I ran into a problem, read this. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962306/sqlite3-and-postgres-heroku-ruby-on-rails-query-issues` It is not a good way to use where to state the ON clause. Should use ON instead. Working answer for PG: `@locations_user_rated = Location.joins('INNER JOIN rates  ON rates.rateable_id = locations.id').where('rates.rater_id' => @user)`

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer and made a few suggestions to simplify things. Typically joins like this are hardly ever needed since when the associations are well defined you can send the association name as a symbol, e.g. `joins(:rates)`.

Comment: I understand that you can use `joins(:rates, :other_table_name)` and make use of active model. I did it in some part of the code. However, this is not the case here. I am using `ratyrate` gem. You are absolutely right about the relationship, however, with the use of `ratyrate` gem, there will be a conflict. If I add the relationship to my `location` and `rate` model, it will conflict with the gem. The only way I can do it is to manually join and query the table.  Again, appreciate your explanation, I totally get it. SQLite accept `Join....where(a.c=b.c)` but PG require `join....on(a.c=b.c)`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend taking advantage of ActiveRecord's `has_many`, `belongs_to`, and `has_many through:` functionality.

If you set up a model for each of these tables, with the correct relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, foreign_key: :rater_id
  has_many :rated_locations, through: ratings, class_name: Location.name, source: :rater
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rater, class_name: User.name
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end
```

Then to access the locaitons that a user has rated, you just call

```
user.rated_locations
```

Comment: I will look into this method. I had those defined in models, but I am not familiar how to use. Thank you again!

Comment: @MelvinCh'ng I highly recommend using this method in your codebase. It is one of the most powerful things that Ruby on Rails provides developers. The app's code will end up being considerably more legible and and controllable. This guide should help you learn everything you need to know: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I can't use this method as I am using ratyrate gem. It will conflict with the model. I tried, but it gave me more issues.